# mvn compile phase is deleting the resources copied in process-resources phase

Tags: java, maven

I have a `src` folder that has `resources/META-INF` under it.

If I do `mvn clean process-resources`, I can see all files under `META-INF` ending up in `target/classes/META-INF` folder.

However after this if I do compile `mvn compile`, those files are gone. As if almost, `mvn compile` is overwriting the `target` folder.

So, I need to do `mvn clean compile compile` if I want those resource files to end up in target folder. This way, the second compile will not do anything because says `Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date`.

This happens even if I have nothing in `<build></build>`.

Comment: Even if you have nothing in `<build></build>`, you could have some misconfigured plugin in some parent pom.  Check with `mvn help:effective-pom`.

Comment: You should follow convention over configuration and use the default directory location which means `src/main/resources/`etc. etc. Why have you decided to go a different path? (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) Please also show the full pom file ...